# Precautions for LauncherOne off centerline drop

Tags: boeing-747, ailerons, payload

Virgin Orbit's [LauncherOne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LauncherOne) is carried in the spare engine position of its [747 carrier aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Girl_(aircraft)) inboard from the inner engine on the portside wing. At launch, the orbital launch vehicle is dropped from the aircraft in midair.
According to Wikipedia, LauncherOne is approximately 30 tonnes. The actual weight could be less, but in any case that seems like a lot of weight off centerline to drop in midair.
To me that looks like it could be a problem, but it is clearly feasible since it has been done already.

What sort of precautions are are needed to do this safely? Is it just a matter of leisurely adjusting aileron trim after launch, or is some special preparation needed for this specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that the aircraft is not flying level at the point of release. The aircraft does a "zoom climb" maneuver and is pitched steeply nose-up at the moment of release. This is going to dramatically reduce the roll.

Public videos of the launches are hard to find but they are out there... The 747 does roll right somewhat, but in an aircraft with a takeoff weight around 900,000 pounds or 400+kg, there's going to be plenty of control surface authority to keep things from going crazy when 60,000 pounds are released from the inboard portion of the wing.